# Как скрыть вывод комментариев php

Tags: регулярные-выражения, bash

Подскажите пожалуйста, как скрыть вывод комментариев php в bash используя регулярные выражения.
Например, что бы скрыть комментарии bash я использую sed

```
cat /etc/samba/smb.conf | sed '/#/d'
```

А как скрыть многострочные комментарии

```
/* Это многострочный комментарий
       еще одна строка комментария */
```

Comment: А у вас GNU sed? Может ли быть ещё текст на тех же строчках, где находится комментарий? Может, `sed '/\/\*/, /\*\//d' file  >  newfile`?

Comment: С очень большой долей вероятности - да.

Comment: Большое спасибо, то, что нужно!

Comment: Если подходит интерпретатор awk, то команда будет выглядеть так: `awk '/\/\*/,/\*\// {next}1' /путь к файлу`

Comment: так же дополню, что `sed '/#/d'` удалит строку, даже если она будет комментарием после параметра или команды, по типу: `public = no #Отключаем публичность` правильнее указывать что решетка должна быть в начале строки символом `^`, т.е. `sed '/^#/d'`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew первый вариант убрал вывод как отдельных, так и комментарии непосредственно в строке.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%5D+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте

```
sed '/\/\*/,/\*\//d' file > newfile
```

Эта команда найдёт и удалит все строки, начиная со строчки, содержащей `/*` до первой строчки далее, содержащей `*/`.

См. [пример работы скрипта](https://ideone.com/AwGWz4):

```
s="Text
/* comment
here */
More text";
sed '/\/\*/,/\*\//d' <<< "$s"
```

Результат:

```
Text
More text
```